# Pivot by year and also get the sum of all amounts Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have data like this

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing is: pivot, create an array and sum values within the array

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

s =df.groupby('id').pivot('year').agg(sum('amount'))#Pivot
(s.withColumn('x', array(*[x for x in s.columns if x!='id']))#create array
         .withColumn('x', expr("reduce(x,cast(0 as bigint),(c,i)-> c+i)"))#sum
        ).show()
```

OR use pysparks inbuilt aggregate function

```
s =df.groupby('id').pivot('year').agg(sum('amount'))#Pivot
(s.withColumn('x', array(*[x for x in s.columns if x!='id']))#create array
 .withColumn('x', expr("aggregate(x,cast(0 as bigint),(c,i)-> c+i)"))#sum
).show()
```

Comment: Hi @wwnde,  I tried your code but I am getting an error as below
'Undefined function: 'reduce'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 0'
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I have already got that statement. Still getting that error.

Comment: me bad, `from functools import reduce` or use aggregate, see my edits

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I have used aggregate, getting this error now -
cannot resolve 'aggregate(`x`, CAST(0 AS BIGINT), lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS DOUBLE) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires bigint type, however, 'lambdafunction((CAST(namedlambdavariable() AS DOUBLE) + namedlambdavariable()), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of double type.;

Comment: Its complaining about the dtype. For what you provided, it was all bigint, looks like you have double dtypes. can you replace the `bigint` with `double`

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I have changed to double and it didn't complain. But when there are nulls for few years and values for some years, it's giving nulls in the total column.  How do I change nulls to 0 when summing in the aggregate function?

Comment: Lets try coalesce, `s =df.groupby('id').pivot('year').agg(sum('amount'))#Pivot
(s.withColumn('x', array(*[x for x in s.columns if x!='id']))#create array
 .withColumn('x', expr("aggregate(x,cast(0 as double),(c,i)-> c+coalesce(i,0))"))#sum
).show()`

Comment: Hi @wwnde, just one last question. What if I want to sum the values only from 2020 and not all years. How do I do that?

Comment: `df.where(col('year')==2019).groupby('id').agg(sum('amount').alias('sum')).show()`

Comment: Hi @wwnde, I want to pivot by all years but show total aggregate only from 2020. How do I do that?

Comment: Cant answer more than two questiions in comment. Afraid you may have to ask a new question

Comment: Hi @wwnde, sure, I have raised another question here. Please can you advise
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74243541/pivot-by-year-and-get-sum-of-amounts-from-2020