# Pivot by year and get sum of amounts from 2020

Tags: pyspark, pivot

I have data like this

[image]

I want to pivot by year and show the total only from 2020

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this as below using [PIVOT](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) on `year` and aggregate [SUM](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html) on `amount` and further use [reduce](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) and [add](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) to generate `total`

#### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [1]*5,
     "type": ['A','A','A','B','B'],
     "year": [2019,2020,2021,2019,2021],
     "amount":[50,75,100,25,75]
    })


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+---+----+----+------+
| id|type|year|amount|
+---+----+----+------+
|  1|   A|2019|    50|
|  1|   A|2020|    75|
|  1|   A|2021|   100|
|  1|   B|2019|    25|
|  1|   B|2021|    75|
+---+----+----+------+
```

#### Pivot - All

```
from operator import add

sparkDF_pivot = sparkDF.groupBy("id","type")\
                         .pivot("year")\
                         .agg(F.sum(F.col('amount')))\
                         .fillna(0)
    
sparkDF_pivot.withColumn('total',reduce(add, [F.col(x) for x in sparkDF_pivot.columns if x not in ['id','type']]))\
             .show()


+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
| id|type|2019|2020|2021|total|
+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
|  1|   B|  25|   0|  75|  100|
|  1|   A|  50|  75| 100|  225|
+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
```

#### Pivot - Specific Year Example

```
from operator import add

sparkDF_pivot = sparkDF.groupBy("id","type")\
                         .pivot("year")\
                         .agg(F.sum(F.col('amount')))\
                         .fillna(0)
    
sparkDF_pivot.withColumn('total',reduce(add, [F.col(x) 
                 for x in sparkDF_pivot.columns if x not in ['id','type',2019]]))\
             .show()


+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
| id|type|2019|2020|2021|total|
+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
|  1|   B|  25|   0|  75|   75|
|  1|   A|  50|  75| 100|  175|
+---+----+----+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi @Vaebhav, I could get until that. How do I get the total from 2020?

Comment: Updated the answer , do upvote and accept if it helped you

Comment: Hi @Vaebhav, I want the total only from the year 2020 and not all year's total

Comment: you can easily do that by selecting the respective `year` column after the pivot

Answer (score 1):

Use slice. In this case I have a list `[2019, 2020, 2021,...]` using `slice(array, startpostion, length)` I can leave out `2019` by starting at position `2` and going the length of the `size of the array`.

```
s =df.groupby('id').pivot('year').agg(sum('amount'))#Pivot
(s.withColumn('x', array(*[x for x in s.columns if x!='id']))#create array
 .withColumn('x', expr("aggregate(slice(x, 2, size(x)),cast(0 as double),(c,i)-> c+coalesce(i,0))"))#sum
).show()
```

data

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [1]*5,
     "type": ['A','A','A','B','B'],
     "year": [2019,2020,2021,2019,2021],
     "amount":[50,75,100,25,75]
    }))
```

solution

```
+---+----+----+----+-----+
| id|2019|2020|2021|    x|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
|  1|  75|  75| 175|250.0|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
```